Error: The role is invalid. WorkOS not working
enter image description here
I am working with WORKOs and somehow I am getting this error of Role is invalid
I think the problem might be with this role is not defined or not included in workos system
'use server';

import {WorkOS} from "@workos-inc/node";
import {revalidatePath} from "next/cache";
import {redirect} from "next/navigation";

const workos = new WorkOS(process.env.WORKOS_API_KEY);

export async function createCompany(companyName: string, userId:string) {
  const org = await workos.organizations.createOrganization({name: companyName});
  await workos.userManagement.createOrganizationMembership({
    userId,
    organizationId: org.id,
    roleSlug: 'admin',
  });
  revalidatePath('/new-listing');
  redirect('/new-listing');

could be here


Go to workos>roles
Add new role (not permissions)
Try add the company again, it should work fine :)

